# add li to ul from json data

Tags: jquery, json, html-lists

I am adding `li` to `ul` from `json` data using for each loop

I have tried following code

```
$("#accordion li").remove();
$.each(jsonData, function( index, value ) {
console.log(value.SubCategoryName)
$("#accordion").append('<li><a id="'+value.subCategoryID+'" style="cursor: pointer;">"'+value.SubCategoryName+'</a></li>');

})
```

It is letting me clear old values from `ul` and console is also showing values. But I am not able to append to `ul` . Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#accordion ul li:last").after('<li><a>Test</span></a></li>');
```

Try after insted of append.

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty string - use that to create a string of the li's and then pass that directly into the html of the accordion.

This will both create the list of li's and secondly will totally replace the html of the ul with the new string. One advantage of this method - you are affecting the DOM only once - one hte content replacement - rathe than with each loop iteration using .append().

I have just dodgied up a jsonData object ot iterate over to create the ul li's.

Aslo note that the a's should have href attributes and that the styling on hover has been moved to the CSS block.

```js
var jsonData = [{
'subCategoryID': '1',
'SubCategoryName': 'Category one',
}, {
'subCategoryID': '2',
'SubCategoryName': 'Category two',
}, {
'subCategoryID': '3',
'SubCategoryName': 'Category three',
},];

var liStr = '';
$.each(jsonData, function( index, value ) {
  liStr +='<li><a id="'+ value.subCategoryID + '">'+ value.SubCategoryName + '</a></li>';
})

$("#accordion").html(liStr);
```

```css
#accordion li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="accordion"></ul>
```